# Multicast listener port in use

Tags: c#, network-programming, multicast

I am new to multicast programming. So far I can successfully send and receive multicast messages from two separate processes (a sender and a receiver). My problem is with the receiver...

---

**ReceiverCode**:

```
private static void ReceiveMulticastMessages()
{
    var groupEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("238.8.8.8"), 23888);
    var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 23888);

    using (var udpClient = new UdpClient())
    {
        udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        udpClient.Client.Bind(localEndPoint);
        udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(groupEndPoint.Address, localEndPoint.Address);

        while (true)
        {
            var remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            var bytes = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint);
            var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The above code works as long as I specify port **`23888`** for the **`localEndPoint`**. If I change the local port number, no messages are received. I would prefer to set it to **`0`** so the OS could choose the port. Why can I not specify a different local port than that of multicast group?

Assuming the local endpoint port must match the multicast group port, how does a client deal with a local port conflict?

On the flip side, how can an application (a multicast sender) choose a multicast group port such that any subscribers will not have a port conflict?

Comment: You have to use the port number that the senders are sending to. You can't just use another one, and you certainly can't use a system-allocated one.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is the sender is sending to the group endpoint 238.8.8.8:8888. I obviously listen on a different endpoint. Why does my listener port even matter?

Comment: @skataben Neither the local port of the sender nor the receiver does matter. What matters is the port of the multicast address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending any UDP message (not just muticast messages), the port that the sender sends to **must** match the port that the receiver is listening on.  That's how messages get to the right place.  If a message is sent to a port other that the one the receiver is bound to, the receiver won't get it.

So a port number needs to be defined that the receiver(s) will listen on and the server will send to.